# how to unicode search in django

Tags: django, unicode

I want to search something in unicode character like `ŞÇİÖÜ`

I define a seach function like that:

```
def search(request):
    from django.db.models import Q
    q = request.GET.get("search", "")
    k = q.split()
    list=[]
    for i in k:
        query = Q(title__icontains=i) | Q(content__icontains=i) 
        posts = Post.objects.filter(query).distinct().order_by('date')
        list.append(posts)
        total = 0
        if list[0]:
            total += len(list)

    return render_to_response('search_results.html', RequestContext(request, {
        "list": list,
        "q": q,
        "total": total,
    }))
```

I have `LANGUAGE_CODE = "UTF-8"`. When I want to search `'Şeker Öçü'` it returns nothing ,although I have `şeker öçü` in posts.

Answer (score 0):

The query string that you obtain from `request.GET.get("search", "")` is in `ISO-8859-8`, but Django's default encoding is UTF-8.

You will have to change either `DEFAULT_CHARSET` or `HttpRequest.encoding` to `ISO-8859-8` to get the correct Unicode data. ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-charset )

Comment: when I add request.encoding = 'ISO-8859-8' before q = request.GET.get("search", "") it returns �eker �¶�§�¼ instead of 'şeker öçü'

Comment: which db are you using btw? mysql? postgresql? and is the LC_COLLATION in utf-8?